# Sending data from a child activity onActivityResult() to parent activity onActivityResult()

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have an App with 2 Activities. Activity A (parent) starts Activity B (child) by calling:

```
startActivityForResult(intentB,B_Request);
```

Activity B is a barcode scanner. (I use this library: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar).
In this activity I have to override the onActivityResult() method in order to get the scanned code. After that I want to send the data stored in 'code' back to the parent (Activity A) onActivityResult(). I did this like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String code = null;

        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents() == null){
                return;
            }
            else {
                code = result.getContents();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);
        intent.putExtra("scannedCode", code);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
}
```

The parent onActivityResult() looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                String scannedCode = data.getStringExtra("scannedCode");
                toastMessage("Scanned code: " + scannedCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following exception and instead of seeing Activity A, I'm redirected to the Activitie's A parent.

```
E/ActivityManager: Failed to schedule configuration change
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1177)
        at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:1815)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:129)
        at com.android.server.am.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
        at com.android.server.am.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:100)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateGlobalConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:24782)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateDisplayOverrideConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:24902)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateDisplayOverrideConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:24879)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.ensureVisibilityAndConfig(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1671)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1420)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1709)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:3043)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2488)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2234)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked(ActivityStack.java:1745)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityPausedLocked(ActivityStack.java:1669)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(ActivityManagerService.java:9657)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:224)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3820)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
```

p.s. It's not enough for me to get the code in Activity B, I need the code back in Activity A.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put **new intent()** instead of

**new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class)**

in your child activity